# What if $F$ when futures maturity != option maturity?

Tags: options

Given an option on an underlying future, where the option matures at $T_1$ and the future matures at $T_2$, and $T_2 > T_1$, when priced using the Black76 formula, what is $F$?

Is it just the current futures price $F(T_2)$? Or do we need to compute some sort of estimate of what the futures price $F(T_2)$ is seen from point $T_1$? And if so, how do we do that?

Comment: Futures contracts are marked to market. Therefore, the payoff is realized when the option is exercised. Your consideration plays a role with forwards, as shown [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/77239/54838).

Comment: If for example you have May 2024 S&P Futures options, where the underlying is June 2024 S&P Futures (May S&P Futures do not exist). Then I believe in the Black formula you would use T for the third friday in May but F for the June futures.