How Forex option Gamma can be more than 1
Problem statement: How forex option Gamma can be more than 1 (more than deal notional)?
FX option details as below
INRJPY FX Option deal (PUT Option and Sell DEAL)
INR Notional=100
JPY Notional=161.29
Strike price 1.6129
Spot price 1.7092
Maturity 1 year
volatility =10%
interest rate INR =6.35% and
interest rate JPY = -0.019%
Greeks I am getting
Delta =0.56
Gamma =-2.26
Requesting to clarify why Gamma is more than 1 and more than Notional? If more than 1 then How it is derived?

Well, what is displayed will depend on how it's implemented. See for example https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/65827/54838. Where is the value from?

Thanks. The value is from our in-house system

In that case, I'd say it's best to ask in house. All else is guessing.

I’m voting to close this question because Its about an in house pricing system. Any questions about implementation and derivations should be addressed within the firm.

Even Bloomberg also providing similar Gamma. So it is not about any system specific. Requesting to provide appropriate explanation which will be of great help.

In fact, punch the above parameters in any option calculator, the results will be similar. That is Gamma more than 1 and Gamma interms of amount would be 226 which is more than notional 100

Why do you believe that the second derivative cannot exceed $1$?  That is NOT true.  And your own system suggests that that bound is not correct.

The derivative of the option Delta does NOT imply that the increment $\Delta(S_t+\Delta S_t)-\Delta(S_t)$ is equal to $\Gamma(S_t)\Delta S_t$.  That is to say, $\frac{d\Delta(S_t)}{dS_t}$ is not equal to $\frac{\Delta (\Delta(S_t))}{\Delta S_t}$.  Apology of the multiple use of the symbol $\Delta$ here.
