# Theta using black scholes when time to maturity approaches 0

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, quant-trading-strategies, greeks

When time to maturity tends to 0, like on expiry day, denominator $\sqrt t$ in becomes 0 and the first term in the formula becomes large enough to make theta of the contract more than its premium. How should this condition be dealt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that it is common that BS theta exceeds the actual market value of an option if the time to expiry is short.

- Therefore most systems compute theta via finite difference (FD) as a true 1 day bump and reprice theta (shifting the evaluation date one day forward and repricing).
- An additional benefit is that holdidays and weekends can easily be included in the computation (Friday will be a 3 day theta, provided Monday is a working day).

I am using Julia to demonstrate this in an answer to a similar question found [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74749/54838).

A more detailed example demonstrating that Bloomberg's OVML uses this logic and how it compares to quantlib can be found in [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/70297/54838).