# Theta Greek Max Curvature

Tags: option-pricing, greeks, pricing-formulae, theta

how to solve it for max Theta Curvature?

**i'm looking for the pure math glyph formula..**

*it may be related to actually*
*3rd deriva & curvature function..*

Comment: I realize you linked questions that explain it already. What exactly is missing? There is no problem on computing it but little use.

Comment: so whats the math formula?  
https://wikiless.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)?lang=en#Formulas_for_European_option_Greeks

Comment: You can find this by ordinary calculus. Don't ask other to perform that task for you.

Comment: Since theta is anyhow often computed as finite difference ([reason](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74749/54838)), it's more natural to look at finite difference for the second order as well ("theta acc" in the linked question which shows all sorts of relationships and the full code to do it).