# The partial derivative of a call option with respect to $t$

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, stochastic-calculus, european-options

In Black-Scholes related computations, why do we not treat the stock price $S$ as a function of $t$ when taking partial derivatives with respect to $t$? For example, if
$$c(t,T)=SN(d_1)-Ke^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)$$
is the price of a call option and we want to find $\partial C/\partial t$, we never include the term $\partial S/\partial t$ and don't consider $S$ as a function of $t$, but as a separate variable. How can this be justified?

Comment: S is just the current observed spot price.

Comment: So S doesn't change over time?

Comment: What's the partial derivative of x*y with respect to y? By definition, a partial derivative is holding all else equal.

Comment: I get your point; however, S = S(t), so how can we ignore its partial derivative. What if, in your example, x is a function of y? x(y)*y

Comment: It's not a function x(y) though, it's just S. What about IV? Surely S is dependent on VOL? Yet, it's not in the closed form solution, which looks at current S. That's why S is a constant in computing theta or vega. You also hold S constant when you compute a [bump and reprice theta](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74749/54838).

Comment: I know we hold S constant, even when it depends on other variables. My question is, how is it justified?

Comment: The trick is to think of the BS formula as $f(t,x)=xN(d_1)-Ke^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)$ and to define delta as $\Delta=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. Then it's clear that you only differentiate with respect to $x$. The call price is then $c=f(t,S_t)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full dependency on the time t of a process, as the process moves forward, you have to calculate and study the full Ito derivative.

But regarding your question : It depends on what you mean by "justified" and how you are going to use the partial derivative.
Yes, $S(t)$ depends on t. However, the process $S(t)$ here is random and almost nowhere differentiable so taking the derivative would not make much sense in the first place.

The reason we don't take the time derivative of $S(t)$ here though is that we consider formal partial derivatives and not full derivatives.
As a simple example, let us say $S(t) = t^2$ and we consider the function $$z(t) = S(t) \cdot t = S \cdot t$$
We now want to calculate $\partial{z} / \partial{t}$. What would you say this is? It actually depends on how you represent $z(t)$.
If you use the above representation you get $\partial{z} / \partial{t} = S = S(t) = t^2$, but if you represent $z(t)$ as
$$
z(t) = t^3
$$
you instead get $\partial{z} / \partial{t} = 3 \cdot t^2.$ When calculating the formal partial derivatives, you see the variables as placeholders. There is no contradiction here. And as I mentioned in the beginning, the justification depends on how you are using those partial derivatives later.

So in the Black-Scholes formula above, we see the value of $S = S(t)$ as such a placeholder for the value of the process $S(t)$ at a fixed $t$.